# margin-top doesnt move i element

Tags: css, position, margin

I have the following css the margins are no working at all. Here is a [link](http://3jtu.localtunnel.com/~anderskitson/techbasics/blog/) to the live site, keep in mind it is in mobile development so thats why it looks all funny. The element thats not moving is the austin kitson one right beside the tweet

**css**

```
             i{
    font-size:0.6em;
    margin-top:-5px;
    margin-left: -25px;
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:10px;
        }
```

**html**

```
<section class="blogPostsSection">
            <header class="blogPostsHeader">
                <?php edit_post_link('edit', '<p>', '</p>'); ?>
            <h2><?php the_date(); ?></h2>
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            </header>
            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('add_images_here'), 'large');?>
             <?php if( $image !=false ) {?>
            <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php get_the_title(get_field('add_images_here')) ?>" />
            <?php } ?>

            <p>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            </p>

            <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" 
            data-text="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-via="twitterapi" data-lang="en">Tweet</a>
            <script>
            !function(d,s,id){ var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if(!d.getElementById(id)){
                js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
                }
            }
            (document,"script","twitter-wjs");
            </script>

            <a href="http://austin.kitson.org"><i>Austin Kitson</i></a>



        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not including your CSS: All your CSS and JS reference `localhost`. e.g., `http://localhost/~anderskitson/techbasics/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=3.3.3`

Comment: all the styles.css file is set media queries and import other style sheets base.css is where my issue lies.